# I can't use a variable outside my loop (flutter)

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a problem with my flutter app, I'm trying to use a variable to stock the name of a market, but when I use this variable, outside my loop, it showed nothing, I don't know why

```
var markets = [
       ["Marjane", "marjane-offers", 34.0590237712, -6.80169582367],
       ["Auto Hall", "autohall-offers", 34.0636,  -6.7973],
       ["Bricoma", "bricoma-offers", 34.0706, -6.7883],
 ];

for (var i = 0; i < markets.length; i++) {
              // GEOLOCATOR PACK
              double stopLatitude = double.parse("${markets[i][2]}");
              double stopLongitude = double.parse("${markets[i][3]}");

              double distanceInMeters = Geolocator.distanceBetween(startLatitude, startLongitude, stopLatitude, stopLongitude);

                      if (distanceInMeters < 1000) {

                        var nameMarket = markets[i][0];

                      }

                    }




                    return Text('Location always change: \n${data.latitude}/${data.longitude} \n\n A9RAB MAHAL LIK: $nameMarket');
```

(This code checks if I'm close to a store and show to me his name!)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you are referring to the variable `nameMarket`. At the point of the return statement, the variable would not be in scope. What you can do is declare the variable like `String? nameMarket` before the for loop (which would be in scope of the return statement). And then assign to it like `nameMarket = markets[i][0];`

Actually, better yet might be to move the return statement into the if statement if you just want the first store that is close enough without checking the remaining stores.